# change headline of page

Tags: headers

I have a web page which includes menu. In its menu I have some items when I click on each item it's gonna show some subitems in it. for example item name : A. It has A.1 and A.2 subitems. which has A.1.1 and A.1.2 subitems. Now the question is when I go to for example A.1.1 page it's gonna show the A.1.1 headline name. how can I change this headline?

I don't wanna change the page name like A.1.1. I just wanna change the headline of this page

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you say headline.  Like the `<h1>` holding the page title?

Comment: @ZachL the page name. when I add the page it's gonna show the page name under the menu. I wanna change the text under the menu of each page without changing the page name

Comment: How did you create the menus? If you used the built-in WordPress menu system, then there is a way to change [the navigation label](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide#Customising_Menu_Items).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still somewhat unclear as to the question, hope I got it.

You can change the menu item text without changing the post name right from the admin.

[image: screenshot]